# flask and csrf token

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I have started with `python-flask` and `angular` and I have used [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/3/) to handle csrf. With an ajax call it's always giving me 403 error. I'm not getting, what I'm doing wrong here.
 I have gone through many answers and have tried all the options found in the [google search](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=3NAQV_3kLeeK8Qec-6DACA#safe=active&q=flask%20%2B%20angularjs%20%2B%20csrf%20). But no luck. I'm not getting where I'm doing a mistake.

Flask Code:

```
@app.route('/targetapi/', methods=['POST'])
def fetch_targets():
  """ """
  data_dict = {}
  acc_ids = request.args['acc_ids']
  data_dict['username'] = session.get('username')
  data_dict['targets'] = some_func(acc_ids)
  return jsonify(data_dict)
```

Angular code:
   HTML Page :

```
<input name="_csrf_token" type=hidden  ng-model="csrf_token" ng-init="csrf_token='{{ csrf_token() }}'" >
```

Ajax call:

```
$http({
         method : "POST",
         url : '/targetapi/',
         headers : { xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',  xsrfCookieName :  csrf_token },
         data : {  acc_ids : accountIDs  }                  
})
```

Not sure why I'm getting  403 Forbidden response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.</p>
```

*response pasted from Chrome-Developer Tool

Comment: How do you setup Flask to protect from CSRF? Flask-WTF? Flask-SeaSurf? Some other method?

Comment: @JakubP. - flask_wtf

Comment: Assuming 1) you read carefully through all of http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html and 2) the AJAX call actually does have the X-CSRFToken header with proper value from the HTML page inserted in the Flask template, and 3) your flask_wtf config isn't changed from default (http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html) then I have no clue... if you could put together a minimal working demo I could try debugging on my own machine... (note the 0.9.0 version requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if Chrome is sending an Options request before the Post request. If so, you can try something like:

```
from flask import current_app

    @app.route('/targetapi/', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
    def fetch_targets():
        if request.method=='OPTIONS':
            response = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        else:
          data_dict = {}
          acc_ids = request.args['acc_ids']
          data_dict['username'] = session.get('username')
          data_dict['targets'] = some_func(acc_ids)
          return jsonify(data_dict)
```